# Pipeline Report

Tags: reporting, servicecloud, sales-cloud, pipelines

How can I build a report that tells me how much pipeline has been added to Salesforce by week and by agents? Historically speaking, I want to go back and look at the last 6 months.

Answer (score 2):

This should do you:

1. Click "New Report"
2. Expand "Opportunities"
3. Click "Create"
4. Find the column "Created Date"
5. Click the small down arrow next to the "Created Date"
6. Click "Group by this field"
7. Click on the down arrow on the left side of the dark blue line that was created
8. Click on Group Dates By > Calendar Week
9. Find the column "Opportunity Owner"
10. Click the small down arrow next to "Opportunity Owner"
11. Click "Group by this field"
12. Next to Preview, click "Summary Format" then click "Matrix Format"
13. Next to Matrix Format, click "Show"
14. Click "Details" to remove the checkbox
15. At the top, above the filters text area, click the down arrow next to the Date Field
16. Select "Created Date"
17. Click the down arrow for Range, select "All Time"
18. Click "Add" next to Filters
19. First box in filters: "Created Date"
20. Second box in filters: "equals"
21. Third box in filters: "last 180 days"
22. Click "OK"